# How to Complete a For Loop to Set Values from list in One Sheet from Another?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below function is meant to loop through the 'POTemplate' tab of my Google Sheet file and get several values starting in row 24 and list them out in a separate 'POHistory' tab within the same file.  Currently, it is only grabbing those details from row 24 and is posting them 10 times to the 'POHistory' tab.  Instead, I need it to getValues from only those cells that are populated in the POTemplate from row 24 to 34 and post to 'POHistory' once per entry.  Hoping I am clear.

```
function Submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var orderSheet = 
app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var i = 24;
 for(i = 24; i<= 34; i++) {
  var poNO = orderSheet.getRange("h2").getValue();
  var poDate = orderSheet.getRange("h3").getValue();
  var vendor = orderSheet.getRange("c12").getValue();
  var skuNo = orderSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  var skuDesc = orderSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
  var qty = orderSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  var uom = orderSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  var utCost = orderSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
  var extCost = orderSheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POHistory");
     var nextRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1; 
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(poNO);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 2).setValue(poDate);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 3).setValue(skuNo);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(skuDesc);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 5).setValue(qty);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(uom);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 7).setValue(utCost);
       targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 8).setValue(extCost);
 }}
```

Comment: Your assignment into `skuNo` is outside of your loop. Close/delete this due to simple typographical error. You should use batch methods to read once from the 10-row, 6 column range, manipulate the array to prepend the relevant po information, and then write once to the corresponding 10x8 range. See `array.unshift`, `Range.getValues`, `Range.setValues`

Comment: I understand you have your own approach to writing code like this, but I'd prefer not to have to start from scratch if possible.  Additionally, the code is working as needed, but I need it to not stop once it hits a cell beneath row 24 that is empty in the POTemplate sheet.  Hoping you can help.

Comment: If you need the loop to stop when it hits an empty cell, then check the given cell for a value before reading the rest and writing any more. You should review flow control statements (i.e. `if`, `else if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, `switch`, `continue`, `break`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Submit() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('POTemplate');
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('POHistory');
  var rg=osh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var poNO=vA[1][7];
  var poDate=vA[2][7];
  var vendor=vA[11][2];
  for(var i=24;i<=34;i++){
    var skuNo=vA[i-1][2];
    var skuDesc=vA[i-1][3];
    var qty=vA[i-1][4];
    var uom=vA[i-1][5];
    var utCost=vA[i-1][6];
    var extCost=vA[i-1][7];
    tsh.appendRow([poNO,poDate,skuNo,skuDesc,qty,uom,utCost,extCost]);
  }
}
```